# constant session id for both web page and applet

Tags: java, session, applet

I have a web application that interacts with applet on the client side. On server i store pairs {sessionid->user} for authentication purposes. It means that every request from user must have the same sessionid every time. The problem is that i need applet in my application. Requests from this applet initialize new session and as a result new session id (I think so because request.getSession(false) returns null. am i wrong?). The question is: how can i make applet to use the same session or how can i retrieve current session id using javasript? In this case i can pass it as a parameter to applet. Neither document.cookie nor url address don't contain 'jsessionid' or anything like this. P.S: application works perfectly fine on tomcat. But now it is moved on weblogic.